# How to distinguish between a protobuf repeated field being explicitly set to empty list vs. not set at all (in python)?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I've a repeated field in my protobuf that's exposed to callers. I'd like to know if the caller explicitly set it to empty list or if the field was not set at all.

The HasField method does not work for repeated fields, so I tried enumerating all the set fields using ListFields method. Unfortunately, irrespective of whether I do a "message.repeated_field.extend([])" or don't set the field at all, the field does not show up in ListFields().

Is it even possible to distinguish between repeated fields being set to empty vs not set all? If so, any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: You say: " I'd like to know if the caller explicitly set it to empty list or if the field was not set at all." Why is that? I don't see that it would matter?

Comment: I am running into the same issue.  I am trying to flatten a message hierarchy and remove messages that only serve to wrap a repeated field.  A workaround to your dilemma might be to wrap your repeated fields to in optional wrapper messages.

Comment: @petersv - the same reason you'd want to distinguish between the two for a non-repeated field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything I've seen says it is not possible to distinguish between the empty repeated fields and unset repeated fields.

I solve it like this:

```
message NameList {
   repeated string names = 1;
}

message SomeResponse {
   optional NameList names = 1;
}
```

Then when you want to send an empty list just initialize the `NameList` field.